# Dropping values only from a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a DataFrame with some string values that I am transforming to integer, for future calculations. The values from column `df['Age']` have some errors that are marked as `NaN` values. Using `dropna` function I lose a half of entire rows and a lot of data  that is in others columns. How can I select for further calculations only the values from `df['Age']` that are not `NaN` values without changing the main DataFrame.

```
df['Age'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], 'coerce').notnull(), df['Age'], NaN)
df = df.dropna(subset=['Age'])
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataframe

Comment: How exactly do you want the NaNs to be handled?

Comment: Did you tried: `.dropna()`?... I did not understood you sorry!

Comment: @ tumbleweed   
When I use `dropna()` the function delete the entire
 row. I need the data from the same row but from another column so `dropna()` is not the ri
ght function. I want to select the data from `df['Age']` 
without the  `NaN` values perform some calculation with it but not to delete any rows. I need to clean the data in the column bou
nduaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the rows with age not null:

```
df[df.Age.notnull()]
```

Or perhaps you want the age only:

```
df[[df.Age.notnull()].Age
```

Comment: Thanks, the second gives the desired result

Answer (score 0):

After you converted `df['Age']` to numeric, use another variable with slicing.

for example, assuming you have an `income` field:

```
another_df = df['income'][~ps.isnull(df['age'])] * 2
```

or, more generally:

```
another_df = df['income'][~ps.isnull(df['age'])].apply(lambda x: x*2)
```

and you can use any function in the `apply` call

**Note: your original dataframe `df` remains unchanged**